# JavaScript Date Object - How Do You Convert a Generic Date to Start of Day Today?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date in string format that looks like:

```
2016-11-02
```

I use `date('2016-11-02')` to convert it to a JavaScript date object.  My local timezone is EST and the above will return:

```
Tue Nov 01 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I would like the generic date input above (without a timestamp) and the date function to return:

```
Wed Nov 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Adding `EST` to the end of the string gives me `Wed Nov 02 2016 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`.  I am looking for `Wed Nov 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

Comment: @JohanKarlsson That did the trick.  Is using `EDT` safe for daylight savings adjustments?  I don't want to be an hour ahead this Sunday

Comment: @JohanKarlsson—that is poor advice. Date strings do not have a time zone associated with them. Parsing a date plus time zone is entirely implementation dependent and is therefore unreliable. Also, there is no standard for time zone names or abbreviations, EST may represent any one of 3 different time zones with different offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse), a string like "2016-11-02" should be parsed as UTC, so in time zones with an offset other than 00:00, it will represent some time other than 2016-11-02 00:00:00.

If you want an ISO 8601 format date string to be parsed as local, you will have to do it yourself or use a library. A simple function to parse as local is:

```js
/* Parse an ISO 8601 format date string as local
** @param {string} s - date in yyyy-mm-dd format
** @returns {Date} "local" date for provided string, or an
**                  invalid date if string is invalid.
*/
function parseISOasLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

console.log(parseISOasLocal('2016-11-02').toLocaleString());
```

Comment: What's the added value of having the `d.getMonth() == b[1]` check in the ternary statement?

Comment: It checks that the values for day and month are valid, so `parseISOasLocal('2016-13-01')` and `parseISOasLocal('2016-12-32')` will return an invalid date rather than one for 2017-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var myDate = '2016-11-02';

// UTC
console.log(new Date(myDate).toUTCString());

// Local
console.log(new Date(myDate).toTimeString());
```

The first log will return you the UTC time and the second will give you the local time.